# Why isn't my component file applying to my react app?

Tags: reactjs, components

I am calling the props on the component instance, but they won't apply to the page.

this is the App.js code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import MovieList from "./components/MoviesList"



function App() {

  const [ getMovies, setMovies ] = useState([
  {
    "Title": "The Hunger Games",
    "Year": "2012",
    "imdbID": "tt1392170",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4NDg3NzYxMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTgyNzkyNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
  },
{
    "Title": "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire",
    "Year": "2013",
    "imdbID": "tt1951264",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTAyMjQ3OTAxMzNeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDU0NzA1MzAx._V1_SX300.jpg"
},
{
    "Title": "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1",
    "Year": "2014",
    "imdbID": "tt1951265",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxNDI2NDAzNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODM3MTc2MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
},
{
    "Title": "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2",
    "Year": "2015",
    "imdbID": "tt1951266",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjQzNDI2NTU1Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTAyMDQ5NjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
}, 
{
    "Title": "The World Is Watching: Making the Hunger Games",
    "Year": "2012",
    "imdbID": "tt2327114",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "N/A"
}]) 



  return (
    
    <div>
      <MovieList movies={getMovies}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and this is the component i'm trying to use:

```
import React from "react"



const MovieList = (props) =>{
    <>
        {props.movies.map((movie, index)=> <div>
            <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
        </div>)}
    </>
}


export default MovieList;
```

when i refresh the browser, the components won't apply, i checked my code multiple times, and i wasn't able to notice what the problem was.

Comment: change `getMovies` to just `movies` so your states will look like: 

        `const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState`. Dont forget to update in MovieList :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the `return` statement (without `return` it won't show anything as you want it to)

```
const MovieList = (props) =>{
    <>
        {props.movies.map((movie, index)=> {
         return (
           <div>
            <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
           </div>
           )
         })}
    </>
}
```

or you can do like this as simpler (if you want):

```
const MovieList = ({movies}) =>{
    <>
        {movies.map((movie, index)=>{
          return (
           <div>
            <img src={movie.Poster} alt="movie"></img>
           </div>
          )
        })}
    </>
}
```